# IONIC Build Process is too slow

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

We are working on IONIC 3 project with a concept of multiple apps within a single app, so sort of application hub of 8-10 apps including Banking, Shopping, Travel, Taxi Booking, etc.

We have just started with the project and we have reached around 300+ components already, also we have at-least 20+ custom/3rd party IONIC Native plugins, we are facing following problems.

- Launch time of application somewhere around 30-50sec.
- Live reload takes around a 60-70sec to reload, so development became very slow.
- While debugging using Safari Dev Tools, Safari is getting crashed, so debugging is now almost not possible.
- When we create Production build, it throws JS heap memory error. (Somehow we have fixed it by allocating 8GB memory to NodeJS process.)

What we have already done,

- Our code is modularized, we have used IONIC best practices to create module per page and also implemented Lazy Loading for Modules.
- Using SaaS, JS minification, etc which is provided by IONIC 3 out of the box.

is IONIC right platform to go for this huge application?

Any hint or guideline will help us to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to that, in addition, I got a warning when loading the application that was loaded very slowly. In my case, use the cordova commands ("android" is the platform wich is giving problems to you, you can use ios, windows...):

```
cordova platform rm android
```

After that delete the Cordova Pluggins Folder and use

```
cordova platform add android
```

When Android is installed, use:

```
cordova clean
```

After that use:

```
cordova build
```

Now use your command to start the app. it worked for me. Good luck